# Disable single user

Tags: android

Hiho,
is there a solution to disable my App for one single user?
There is one Person, who buys my app every few days to use the app for calculations, and than deinstalls the app within the 15 Minuts window.

Over 10 times he did it and with the next update i want to create a method, that checks the user mail from market and if its these person, the App should close instantly.
Thanks for Help
Alex

Comment: I am not sure if this is a programming question or one for the market or one for the wish list of Android changes. A completely impractical method would be to make the process last longer than 15 minutes. Another might be to register users giving you some feedback on the user using your app. A final option could be to create a SOA using a webservice to do the work and charge users via an account which is the same cost as the app but make the app free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure this is the same user (and not just a usage trend of one refund every few days)?  A user should only be able to refund an app once.  According to the App Refund article in [Android Market Support](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134336):

> You have 15 minutes from the time of download to return an application purchased through Android Market for a full refund. You may only return a given application once; if you subsequently purchase the same app again, you may not return it a second time.

EDIT:  If it looks like it's the same user, please contact [Android Market Support](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601) and let them know.  Follow the relevant "Contact Us" link at the bottom, and include all relevant information:  App name, user's email address, order ID's, etc.  Abusing the refund policy like this shouldn't be possible.  If it is, they need to know so that hole can be closed :)

Comment: This is probably not enforced in code yet (Which explains why the user is getting away with the repeated uninstalls), but I bet it means that if the developer pushes Google they can initiate a process that forces the user to pay for the app.

Comment: Updated answer with relevant link.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the accounts from accountmanager, as I know to do what you want, checking account is the only way I think. you will need GET_ACCOUNTS permission.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting in hate code for this single user, I'd suggest you put in a little more effort and put in a more generic check.

Whenever a user signs up, check if the user has already used your application, and if he/she has not, save the user's account information on a backend. Else notify him saying that he/she has already checked the application out and if he/she has some feedback. Try to make the user 'guilty' here!

Building a backend system is pretty simple with a service like stackmob.com. Though for this, you'll need to acquire the GET_ACCOUNTS permission, and for a service like calculator, asking for this permission might seem fishy. So you need to make that call here!

Answer (score -1):

If you do figure out how to identify your user rather than close right away you should do stuff that delays them for 15 minutes.

Make them fill out some forms first (Just for that user), stuff that takes time.  Be really specific in the forms with password requirements like 10 chars including upper, lower number and punctuation, then force them to "Log in" using this password (which they won't remember and will have to start over...), but always make it look like each step is the "Last little bit" they will have to do before they can use the app...

Also use a lot of "Contacting server..." and "Calculating" and "Installing" that take time.  If you really need to stretch it out, add a few "Retrying" after the connecting message has been there for a while.

Comment: I know none of us like that user here, but what you are suggesting goes against the spirit of the 15 min free window Bill. This is not a good way to tackle the issue.

Comment: @Vikram Bodicherla My thought is that repeatedly using the 15 minute free window to avoid paying also goes against the spirit, so the gloves are already off and all's fair!  I said only apply these changes to the single person (if you can identify them).  You really think this unfair?